# Why does the Google Play Store sometimes not list an app update?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates

I've noticed that the Google Play Store sometimes does not list an update for an app.

For example, I'm working on a stock, non-rooted, Android Nougat device on which [Firefox Focus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.focus) was installed through the Google Play Store.

The version of Firefox Focus installed is v8.0.5.  When I go to the Google Play Store, I see that v8.0.6 has been available for about a month.  Furthermore, if I manually type `Firefox Focus` into the Google Play Store, it will allow the app to be updated.  Yet, despite all this, when I click on `My apps & games` in the Google Play Store, Firefox Focus does not appear in the list of apps with updates available.

This seems to happen fairly regularly for different apps.

Rebooting does not help.  The device does *not* have removable storage.  I've tried clearing the data and cache for the Google Play Store.  This sometimes fixes the issue temporarily, but then the issue returns.  Similarly, uninstalling and reinstalling the affected app fixes the issue temporarily, but then the issue returns.

Why does the Google Play Store sometimes not list an app update that is available?  Can this be fixed so it doesn't happen anymore?